# What happened to _start and the arguments of __libc_start_main on 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit, elf, disassembly

I'm reading http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html and trying to verify things by hand.

The disassembly of _start is given as follows:

```
080482e0 <_start>: 80482e0: 31 ed xor %ebp,%ebp
80482e2: 5e pop %esi
80482e3: 89 e1 mov %esp,%ecx 
80482e5: 83 e4 f0 and $0xfffffff0,%esp 
80482e8: 50 push %eax 
80482e9: 54 push %esp 
80482ea: 52 push %edx 
80482eb: 68 00 84 04 08 push $0x8048400 
80482f0: 68 a0 83 04 08 push $0x80483a0 
80482f5: 51 push %ecx 80482f6: 56 push %esi 
80482f7: 68 94 83 04 08 push $0x8048394 
80482fc: e8 c3 ff ff ff call 80482c4 <__libc_start_main@plt> 
8048301: f4 hlt
```

However my own disassembly is as follows:

```
0x00000000004003c0 <+0>:     xor    ebp,ebp
0x00000000004003c2 <+2>:     mov    r9,rdx
0x00000000004003c5 <+5>:     pop    rsi
0x00000000004003c6 <+6>:     mov    rdx,rsp
0x00000000004003c9 <+9>:     and    rsp,0xfffffffffffffff0
0x00000000004003cd <+13>:    push   rax
0x00000000004003ce <+14>:    push   rsp
0x00000000004003cf <+15>:    mov    r8,0x400650
0x00000000004003d6 <+22>:    mov    rcx,0x4005c0
0x00000000004003dd <+29>:    mov    rdi,0x40051c
0x00000000004003e4 <+36>:    call   0x4003b0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
0x00000000004003e9 <+41>:    hlt    
0x00000000004003ea <+42>:    nop
0x00000000004003eb <+43>:    nop
```

So my question is simply what happened to the arguments for __libc_start_main that are pushed on the stack in the first disassembly?

My file is "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped." i.e. dynamically linked as the file in http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html is as well.

Is this because my system is 64-bit and the system used in the link is 32-bit? Has the definition of __libc_start_main changed?

Comment: Compiling the program with -m32 on my system gives me similar disassembly as in the linked tutorial.

Comment: The first listing is from an x86 target, the second from an x86-64. The ABI for the two platforms, including function calling conventions, is different. On x86-64, which has more registers available to it, more arguments are passed via register than on the stack, hence the loads into `r8`, `rcx`, and `rdi`.